# HTML5 Image upload with drag & drop, crop & ratio

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I am trying to use the HTML5 Image upload with drag & drop, crop & ratio JS plugin.

I can get it to work as far as getting the widget to run on a page that allows me to zoom in and move it etc. But I am stuck as to save the image, there are many options but no examples. For what I can gather, it posts the data to a URL which I can define with the following data as an example. I assume I have to read this and use it to save the data as a .jpg image? Am I thinking along the correct lines?

Sorry to be vague but I don't really know where to start or what to add as as I new here but any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code on my page is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>HTML5 Image upload width drag and drop, crop and ratio</title>

    <meta name="description" content="A HTML5 image upload plugin build with jQuery. Can drag and drop an image, crop it and change ratio." />

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/html5imageupload.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">

 <div class="dropzone" data-width="960" data-height="540" data-ghost="false" data-canvas="false" data-smaller="true" data-canvas-image-only="true" data-originalsize="false" data-url="" data-resize="true" style="width: 100%;">
            <input type="file" name="thumb" />
          </div>


        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <a name="ghost"></a>
          <h2>Ghosting &amp; Original size</h2>

        </div>

      </div>

      <hr />



   <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/html5imageupload.js"></script>

    <script>

    $('#retrievingfilename').html5imageupload({
        onAfterProcessImage: function() {
            $('#filename').val($(this.element).data('name'));
        },
        onAfterCancel: function() {
            $('#filename').val('');
        }

    });

    $('#save').html5imageupload({
        onSave: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },

    });

    $('.dropzone').html5imageupload();

    $( "#myModal" ).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
        $('#modaldialog').html5imageupload();
    });
    /*
    $('#form').html5imageupload({
        onAfterProcessImage: function() {
            $(this.element).closest('form').submit();
        }
    });

    $('form button.btn').unbind('click').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault()
          $(this).closest('form').find('#form').data('html5imageupload').imageCrop()
    });*/


    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

and an example of what it posts if I am correct is :-

```
The $_POST variable

array(3) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(2) "fg"
  ["title"]=>
  string(2) "fg"
  ["thumb_values"]=>
  string(112422) "{"data":"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgA==","name":"logo.png","imageOriginalWidth":225,"imageOriginalHeight":44,"imageWidth":2762,"imageHeight":540,"width":960,"height":540,"left":-901,"top":0}"
}
The JSON object

object(stdClass)#1 (10) {
  ["data"]=>
  string(112262) "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgA=="
  ["name"]=>
  string(8) "logo.png"
  ["imageOriginalWidth"]=>
  int(225)
  ["imageOriginalHeight"]=>
  int(44)
  ["imageWidth"]=>
  int(2762)
  ["imageHeight"]=>
  int(540)
  ["width"]=>
  int(960)
  ["height"]=>
  int(540)
  ["left"]=>
  int(-901)
  ["top"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

Comment: When you say save, do you mean on the user's machine or on a server?

Comment: To save on the server as a new image, thanks

Comment: No, problem. Your best bet is to read the PHP Documentation on how to do this from a post request ([here's a tutorial on the PHP doc site](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)). All you need to do is point your uploaded file to the php file on your server during upload.

Comment: Will have a look, thanks